# Simple USB drive encryption under Windows - Best Practise?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, encryption, truecrypt

I'm looking for an easy (!) way to encrypt (and decrypt) USB volumes under Windows 10.
Easier than my current practise:
Currently, I've an True Crypt file on the USB volume and a portable TrueCrypt installation on the same stick. I plug the device in, run TC, select the TC file (have to reselect it, since the device has mostly new drive letters), select a drive letter to mount, and click ok, enter the password, ok. Have the new volume with encrypted files in/on.

What I want: Plug the device in - password dialog opens automatically - enter password - device is there (encrypted).

Is this possible with pure Windows capabilities? Or some external tools/workflow?

Thanks
Konrad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be pure Windows, I suggest using BitLocker. It is a builtin Windows functionnality, so you don't need anything else. You just need Windows 7/8 Enterprise or Ultimate, or Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise.

Just right-click your USB key, and click Activate BitLocker.

---

If you don't have Win10 Pro, you can write a Batch script that starts TC with a command to mount the file, and set an Autorun for it. You'll have to google the exact syntax of the command though, I don't have it at hand rigth now (sorry).

Comment: Also, if using BitLocker, make sure to safely remove the drive.

Comment: And if you use the second solution (TC + Autorun), you should also make sure to unmount the TC drive as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the built-in bitlocker encryption tool on windows 10. It's very easy to setup and you should find plenty of tutorials online.

Comment: (we are suppose to be the tutorial)....

Comment: @Ramhound we are ? But this was too easy

Comment: It isn't about how easy something is.  If you submt an answer it should be complete.  If somebody comes here for an answer to their question, they shouldn't have to go "searching" for steps, in order to do what you described in an answer.  *In other words in no uncertain terms, telling somebody they should read tutorials on how to do something, when you didn't tell them how to do that something is not actually helpful.*  If you want to leave a comment, saying those tutorials exist, feel free to do that.

Comment: okay. So you're telling me i shouldn't help ? I write the answer and then everyone loses their minds when i don't explain each and every single step ? The question asked by op was if there were other technologies available already in windows. And i just said yes. Am i required to spoon feed everyone ? It was fairly obvious the op didn't  even google the answers first and showed no proper research. So why should i encourage that ?

Comment: You are clearly not open to feedback with regards to your answer, so in the future, I won't provide it.  The help center has excellent information on what makes a good answer.  Compare your answer to the accepted answer, do you see a difference, then read your answer again.  You could easily improve this answer, make it fit within our community, and make it complete.